# Filter JSON List by comparing date between two others dates ReactJS / Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using this use state hook to store multiple objects of the same type and with the same variables.

```
  const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);
```

When console logging the hook, this is what is printed:

```
[
    {
        "object_id": 1,
        "object_name": "FirstExample",
        "date_created": "2021-03-24 14:19:05",
    },
    {
        "object_id": 2,
        "object_name": "SecondExample",
        "date_created": "2021-03-25 14:19:05",

    }
]
```

**Question:**

My question is how would I filter the JSON list to only have the objects where there date_created attribute is between a StartDate and EndDate variable?

I have tried this but it did not work and the JSON list became empty:

```
const objectsList = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/objects/all")
const objectListJson = await objectsList.json()

let newList = objectListJson.filter(function(){
    return (this).data('date_created') < StartDate || (this).data('date_created') > EndDate;
              }).hide();

setObjects(newList);
```

I have also tried this but again the list became empty

```
setObjects(objectListJson.filter(objectListJson => objectListJson.date_created >= StartDate || objectListJson.date_created <= EndDate ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try like this.

```
let newList = objectListJson.filter(el => el.date_created >= StartDate && el.date_created < EndDate);
```

If `StartDate` and `EndDate` variables are timestamp, try like this.

```
let newList = objectListJson.filter(el => Date(el.date_created) >= StartDate && Date(el.date_created) < EndDate);
```

Comment: @NickWinston Technically, wouldn't filtering for `x < journalStartDate || x > journalEndDate` keep only the objects NOT in that date range? I would think you'd want `x >= journalStartDate && x < journalEndDate` give you the correct range?

Comment: I explained only how to use filter function. I used the conditions of your code.
Now I've changed conditions

Comment: What is the type of `journalStartDate` variable?

Answer (score 2):

You compare strings instead of real date. You should transform your date string to number.
`Date.parse("2021-03-24 14:19:05")` will return number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to achieve this by comparing those date strings as Date object instances. You will also need to specify the timezone if that is a factor. Here is an example:

```js
const objectListJson = [
    {
        "object_id": 1,
        "object_name": "FirstExample",
        "date_created": "2021-03-24 14:19:05",
    },
    {
        "object_id": 2,
        "object_name": "SecondExample",
        "date_created": "2021-03-25 14:19:05",

    },
    {
        "object_id": 3,
        "object_name": "SecondExample",
        "date_created": "2021-04-01 07:19:05",

    }
]

const journalStartDate = new Date(2021, 2, 1) // 2021-03-01 00:00:00
const journalEndDate = new Date(2021, 3, 1) // 2021-04-01 00:00:00

const newList = objectListJson.filter(obj => new Date(obj.date_created) >= journalStartDate && new Date(obj.date_created) < journalEndDate);

//setObjects(newList);

//filters out object 3 because it is not between journalStartDate and journalEndDate
console.log(newList);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { display: block !important; top: 0 !important; max-height: 100% !important; } .as-console { height: 100% !important; } .as-console-row-code { vertical-align: top !important; }
```